# How to do skipwaiting with register-service-worker in vue app?

Tags: vue.js, service-worker

I have the following `registerServiceWorker.ts` in my application

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
        ready() {
            console.log(
                'App is being served from cache by a service worker' 

            )
        },
        registered() {
            console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
        },
        cached() {
            console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
        },
        updatefound() {
            console.log('New content is downloading.')
        },
        updated() {
            console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
            //@ts-ignore
            self.skipWaiting();
        },
        offline() {
            console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
        },
        error(error) {
            console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
        }
    })
}
```

How would I trigger the skipwaiting from code in the updated event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to configure the service worker to automatic skip waiting in my vue application, using vue.config.js.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    lintOnSave: false,
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        ...
    },
    configureWebpack: {
        ...
    },
    pwa: {
        ...
        workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW',
        workboxOptions: {
            skipWaiting: true
        }
    },
    pluginOptions: {
      ...
    },
    css: {
        // Enable CSS source maps.
        sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
    },
    devServer: {
       ...
    }
};
```

Comment: [Ref](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-webpack-plugin.GenerateSW#GenerateSW) - **skipWaiting** (Optional - boolean):  
Whether to add an unconditional call to skipWaiting() to the generated service worker. If false, then a message listener will be added instead, allowing you to conditionally call skipWaiting() by posting a message containing {type: 'SKIP_WAITING'}.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're trying to call skipWaiting from the browser context of the code, not from the Service Worker context.

The code you pasted in your question is executed *by the browser execution thread*, it so calledly "normal JS execution". However, skipWaiting does NOT exist in that execution context. skipWaiting is part of the Service Worker execution context. You can call skipWaiting from the Service Worker script file itself that your browser context JS registers.

This line

```
register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
```

registers a new Service Worker which lives inside a file called "service-worker.js". In *THERE* (that file!) you are able to call self.skipWaiting().

Check out the MDN documentation here. There's an example of calling the method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/skipWaiting

Comment: Thanks, took me a bit of googing to figure out that vue uses google workbox and that it could be configured with the vue.config.js file to skipwaiting. I have not been able to find any way to post a message to workbox and have it skip waiting from code. but thats not needed now.

Answer (score 1):

I just found [this article](https://dev.to/drbragg/handling-service-worker-updates-in-your-vue-pwa-1pip) after 2 days of fighting through various service worker articles. It's a super elegant and *working* (copy/paste) solution to show a snackbar prompt (using vuetify) asking the user if they want to refresh. Highly recommended!